# How to fix "TypeError: Cannot set property 'approved' of null"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, model-view-controller

So my code was all working fine, until on one of my application controllers I added some code, and now it's throwing me this error when I try to POST the data:

```
(node:10928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set
property 'approved' of null
    at store (C:\Users\sadkevin\Desktop\Programs\Rocketseat\SemanaOmnistack9\backend\src\controllers\RejectionController.js:9:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:10928) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10928) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

This is my RejectionController, where I set if the bookings are false (and there is also a ApprovalController that only changes the false value of booking.approved to true, and it throws me the same error):

```
const Booking = require('../models/Booking');

module.exports = {
    async store(req, res) {
        const { booking_id } = req.params;

        const booking = await Booking.findById(booking_id).populate('spot');

        booking.approved = false;

        await booking.save();

        return res.json(booking);
    }
};
```

This is my bookings controller:

```
const Booking = require('../models/Booking');

module.exports = {
    async store(req, res) {
        const { user_id } = req.headers;
        const { spot_id } = req.params;
        const { date } = req.body;

        const booking = await Booking.create({
            user: user_id,
            spot: spot_id,
            date,
        });

        await booking.populate('spot').populate('user').execPopulate();

        const ownerSocket = req.connectedUsers[booking.spot.user];

        if (ownerSocket) {
            req.io.to(ownerSocket).emit('booking_request', booking);
        }

        return res.json(booking);
    }
};
```

This is the MongoDB schema for the bookings:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const BookingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    date: String,
    approved: Boolean,
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    spot: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Spot'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Booking', BookingSchema);
```

And these are the routes of my application:

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const uploadConfig = require('./config/upload');

const SessionController = require('./controllers/SessionController');
const SpotController = require('./controllers/SpotController');
const DashboardController = require('./controllers/DashboardController');
const BookingController = require('./controllers/BookingController');
const ApprovalController = require('./controllers/ApprovalController');
const RejectionController = require('./controllers/RejectionController');

const routes = express.Router();
const upload = multer(uploadConfig);

routes.post('/sessions', SessionController.store);

routes.get('/spots', SpotController.index);
routes.post('/spots', upload.single('thumbnail'), SpotController.store);

routes.get('/dashboard', DashboardController.show);

routes.post('/spots/:spot_id/bookings', BookingController.store);

routes.post('/bookings/:booking_id/approvals', ApprovalController.store);
routes.post('/bookings/:booking_id/rejections', RejectionController.store);

module.exports = routes;
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you paste your bookings model?

Comment: Have you checked if `booking` is not null in `const booking = await Booking.findById(booking_id).populate('spot');`

Comment: I'm kinda new to this universe but, isn't what you are asking the mongoose one? With the BookingSchema.

Comment: put a breakpoint at this line `const booking = await Booking.findById(booking_id).populate('spot');` and see what booking is, its most likely undefined or null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, at Insomnia I was not passing the booking ID, that's why it couldn't set property of null.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what the root cause of the error is, but the `booking` variable is set to null after returning from the Promise. Either the Booking is not found in the db or the `booking_id` is not passed in through the request params. I would recommend wrapping around your async await code in a try catch to help with debugging and see what the console error logged is.

```
async store(req, res) {
   try {
        const { booking_id } = req.params;

        const booking = await Booking.findById(booking_id).populate('spot');

        booking.approved = false;

        await booking.save();

        return res.json(booking);

    } catch (err) {

        console.error(err);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your  approved: Boolean  to approved: Boolean?
in your MongoDB schema

this will allow it to be nullable

Comment: When I put '?' after the type 'Boolean', VSCode doesn't recognize it.